# // Comment in C++ vs /* */ in C

Tags: c++, c, comments

I found that in C there is only a multiline comment that is `/* */`. Why did the designers of C++ introduced single line comments `//` if there is already a multiline comment serving the same purpose.

What are the advantages of using a single line comment `//` in C++ as compared to multiline comment `/* */` in C?

Comment: No. Your thinking is wrong. You can use both single line and multiline comments in C and C++.

Comment: C also supports `//` comments since C99.

Comment: Well, it's two or three characters less to write a single line comment than a block comment. :)

Comment: Additionally, you can use multi-line comments to comment out a block that already contains single-line comments!

Comment: `//` can enclose itself (i.e., `////` is valid), `/**/` can't (i.e., `/*/**/*/` is invalid). That a very a strong argument for using only `//`... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of taste and habits.

Line comments

```
// like this
```

are shorter to type (and acceptable both in C99 code and in C++03 code), and they can be "nested"

```
// nested // line // comment
```

In C or C++ block comments

```
/* like that block
   comment */
```

can be smaller (or much larger) than a line

```
if (/*strange*/ some_test()) {
```

But they cannot be nested:

```
/* WRONG /* NESTED COMMENT */ // is ended here
 but you may want them to nest */
```

Notice that many editors (e.g. `emacs`) or IDEs are aligning/reformatting/highlighting comments. Most of them (and also GNU [indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/)) are able to deal efficiently with

```
/**************************************
 * some boxed block comment
 * like this
 **************************************/
```

PS. In Ocaml some `(*` ... `*)`  comments *can* be nested

Comment: /* */ comments can also be in the middle of a line. This can (sometimes) be useful. /* */ is also subject to forgetting a closing */, causing the merging of two comments and the intervening code (editor formatting aids and perhaps compiler warnings make this less of an issue).

Answer (score 4):

An example:

if you have

```
i=0;
// this is a comment
printf("%d",i);
```

And you want to eliminate this block for a while for debug testing, for example

```
/* 
i=0;
//this is Comment
printf("%d",i);
*/
```

But, If you had:

```
i=0;
/*this is Comment*/
printf("%d",i);
```

You can surely see the problem here:

```
/*
If you had:
i=0;
/*this is Comment*/
printf("%d",i);
*/
```

The compiler will see the first "*/" as the end of the comment block.

Comment: `#if 0` `#endif` works in both case.

Answer (score 2):

The basis for your question is completely wrong, because both C and C++ (and other languages like Objective-C or Java) allow exactly the same kinds of comments.

// comments are more useful to add comments at the end of a line. Using // comments exclusively allows you removing ranges of lines from your code quickly by turning them into /* comments */.

Comment: Much better way to remove range of lines is `#ifdef NOT_DEFINED`...`#endif`.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka: I prefer `#if 0` ... `#endif` to remove lines

Comment: Better because shorter and no need to worry if NOT_DEFINED is actually defined :) - thanks for hint

Comment: Using an `#ifdef 0/not_defined` is a way of letting cruft into the code (it takes a few years of doing it, until you need to follow what macros are defined, just to be able to read the source code). A much better way of removing code is usually the delete key (along with a source control system). Please don't do the macro thing. The maintainers of your code will thank you.

Comment: Macros are good choice for conditional compilation, but not a wise choice for commenting. Search results (for example grep) may be confusion, so prefer delete with source control.

Comment: @utnapistim You never needed to remove some code temporarily during development? Ifdefing it out is the easiest and simplest way. Obviously such code should not be checked in.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka, yes, I know. The thing is, right now I am converting legacy code to 64bit platform and the code (windows only) is full with `#ifdef _WIN32`, `#if 0`, `#ifdef _WIN32` within other `#ifdef _WIN32` blocks and other generic macro abuse. I have also heard the "don't worry, I'm not checking this in" part many many times - and seen it checked in many more times - sometimes with the same author involved :(. Most people tend to check in code when it compiles (or passes some test), not when it compiles and they have reviewed the changes.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I want to tell you is your thinking is wrong that `//` is not allowed in C while both `/* Comment */` and `//` are strongly supported by C.

Another thing is there are many advantages of `//` over `/* */`.

1. You can comment partial line of the code upto end using `//`
2. Adding `//` saves a lot of time while developing

Answer (score 0):

> What are the advantages of using a single line comment // in C++ as compared to multiline comment /* */ in C?

Single line comments can be embedded in multi-line comments. This allows you to comment blocks of code on the fly (if you have code with single line comments, you can just add `/*` and `*/` and recompile.

If you have block comments instead, you cannot surround the code with `/*` and `*/` (as the block will instead be broken at the first existing comment block end.

> I found that in C there is only a multiline comment that is /* */

It's a common misconception, caused by the fact that these comments were not supported by C before the C99 standard. Old projects (legacy code), may still not support them, depending on compiler options.

Answer (score -1):

Note: Comments have no effect on compiled programmed they are skipped they are only for programmer or Reader to understand whats going on.

C++ introduce single line comments because while coding its easy to use // for single line comment instead of /**/.

Programmer are free to use any style for coding but // is good to comment 1 or 2 lines while more then 2 lines then its good practice to use multi line comment style.

I hope you will understand and you will also experience the difference when do programming.